# Excel Covariance Matrix with #N/A data

Tags: vba, excel, matrix, covariance

I am trying to compute a covariance matrix on time series data of stocks (with a sample of it shown here). I am trying to put together a code that allows me to compute the covariances for flexible dates and place it in a matrix table. However I keep getting stumpted by the #N/A values. Is there any way to get the rows that include #N/A values to be ignored in the calculation and thus allow me to get a covariance value? Do I need to sort the data first? Hints on making the code flexible to different date ranges would also be appreciated. Many thanks[image: data]

Comment: You can use an "IF(ISERROR(YourFunction),"",YourFunction)" on all the individual functions, and this will set everything to blank and should ignore those cells.  Only if you have control over the functions entered into the sheet.

Comment: Thanks. As the correl function ignores blanks this works well. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISNA function can be used to check for a #N/A (value not available) error.
eg =`IF(ISNA(B1),"",B1)` It would check for #N/A in cell B1 and if its true it would make it blank or anything which you want to specify else it would print B1 value.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the comment, that is certainly useful to know. works well by including the function as per the comment above from Kevin.